# Build AOSP: How to include files on SD card?

Tags: android, build, android-sdcard, android-source

I'm building 4.4 for a device and adding some vendor-specific additions - a few APKs and some files on the shared storage.

I've added a vendor module to the source tree to copy the APKs with `PLATFORM_COPY_FILES` task, but it looks like that's only applicable to files in the system image.

Is this possible within the existing android build system?

Comment: So I haven't found any way to do this through the build system but you can sort of hack it though I'm not sure exactly how. You can make an APK that responds to the onBoot broadcast which will write some assets out to a directory of your choice. I know some other APKs I have in my build system are doing *something* like this, but you'd have to experiment to get it to work.

Comment: @AndrewT. Thanks, that sounds like it would work. Next step: figure out how to get AOSP to build that APK...

Comment: This seems interesting so I'm working on an application to do this. Ill post a link to the git repo of it when I'm done. Being able to just load files to the sdcard seems useful in general.

Comment: It doesn't really seem like your problem is with the build system, but rather with the *deploy* system which you are using to install on devices.  It will need an extra step to pre-load the storage.

Answer (score -1):

So since there doesn't seem to be a way to do this via AOSP, you need to use an app which adds the files at boot time. I have created a package that you can find here:

https://github.com/Paradopolis/AssetCopier

I just whipped this up so there may be some bugs, if you find them feel free to send a pull request or raise an issue and ill take a look. The code isn't complicated however.

Comment: This seems terribly wasteful of space - you'll still retain (perhaps compressed) copies within that APK itself on the device.

Comment: @ChrisStratton It certainly is, but I'm not sure how to make it much better. The files have to be included by an apk, and multiple users may need these files. If you remove the apk after it's done it's job, new users will not get these files. Unfortunately, android doesn't seem to offer much of an alternative.

Comment: I think the problem is with the *assumption* that this must be done by an apk.  Though an apk pulling data from some off-device source could be an option.  But I think the real solution depends on understanding the method of device imaging to be used in factory production.

Comment: @ChrisStratton From what I know of AOSP, for a file to be included in a user directory it would have to be. If it could be included at a later time, then the file would still need to be stored somewhere in a system directory so that when a second user is created (i.e. on a tablet) then the file gets added to that user. If there is an alternative method for doing this that you know, I would love to hear it, post it as an answer. For now, this is the only answer anyone can seem to provide, so it's the best that we have.

Comment: Duplicating pre-installed content across users sounds sub-optimal, unless it's something they are expected to delete.  Does Android ship anything by default on the External Storage?  Perhaps the idea of putting information there to begin with is the problem.  Remember also that a *system vendor* is not limited to apk's in the way that a 3rd party developer is.

Comment: @ChrisStratton It certainly is sub-optimal but that also isn't the question. If you look at the Google hangouts app, it seems to place files onto the SDCard, but android at base does not seem to copy anything there. It's not the ideal way of doing things, but if you need to place a few small files into the only area that is really publically available, then this still seems to be the only way to do  it. This conversation is getting a bit long though, if you want to discuss more feel free to invite me to a chat room.